# Very ample divisors on blow ups of the projective plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, blow-ups, ample-bundles

Let $X$ be $\mathbb{P}^2$ blown up at $k$ points in general position. The Picard group of $X$ is just $\mathbb{Z}^{k+1}$ and one knows the intersection product explicitly. If $D$ is an ample divisor, one can easily and explicitly compute its global sections since the points are in general position. Knowing all this, I would expect that one can also decide whether a given ample divisor $D$ is in fact very ample. Has this been carried out? Is there a nice criterion known?

Comment: The paper *General blow-ups of the projective plane* by Szemberg and Tutaj-Gasinska (Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 130, nr. 9, 2515-2524 (2002) gives a good overview of the known results.

Comment: Probably I'm missing something, but how do you compute the global sections?  There's an obvious dimension count, but it's not so clear that it gives the right answer, even when points are very general.

Comment: thanks abx! that looks good. @Mark: I thought that for a fixed ample divisor, the set of tuples of points where the obvious dimension count is correct is Zariski dense, isn't it?

Comment: @Hans It could be; I don't know the results here very well.  It's not the case if you drop the ampleness assumption, since the dimension count suggests $h^0(2H-2E_1-2E_2)=0$ on the 2-point blow-up, when the right number is $h^0=1$.  But with ample, maybe it's OK -- do you know what the reference is? (Surely this would follow from the SHGH conjecture, but maybe one doesn't need it.)